# CSS Background Repeat Image Margin Top

Tags: css, background, margin, repeat

So I already know a lot of people have asked this. Such as here:

[css start repeating background from defined position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604663/css-start-repeating-background-from-defined-position/5604702)

[Background position, margin-top?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9743717/background-position-margin-top)

[CSS Background repeat issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16393190/css-background-repeat-issue)

[css start repeating background from defined position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604663/css-start-repeating-background-from-defined-position)

[Background Margin-top effect with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18262946/background-margin-top-effect-with-css)

I have literally tried ALL of these methods, properly, and it's not working. I am trying to have a repeatable background start 100px from the top or 'normal' position.

```
<style>
.moiraitable{
width:500px;
background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/owEfTJa.png");
background-repeat: repeat-y;
background-position: center 100px;
background-size: 510px;
}
</style>
<div class="moiraitable">
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/EXYfcOt.png" style="width:500px;margin:0 auto;" />
<p style="text-align:justify;margin:10px 40px;color:white;">
Proin iaculis pharetra tempus. 
Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. 
Vestibulum tincidunt justo nec orci tempus, quis sagittis lacus eleifend. Praesent id justo eget magna lacinia feugiat. In a risus commodo, consectetur diam id, pellentesque quam. Vivamus accumsan vehicula ligula, in tristique lorem scelerisque sed. Aliquam ante urna, bibendum adipiscing tincidunt eu, posuere non turpis. Vivamus vitae porta urna. Suspendisse consequat nisi semper lectus ullamcorper, et tempus augue convallis. Duis ante lacus, bibendum eget diam at, dignissim blandit dui. Nunc placerat purus vel arcu feugiat, viverra semper velit tristique. Proin magna lectus, bibendum ac lectus at, semper sagittis nunc. Duis ornare quam ac convallis sagittis. Nam convallis quis urna eu vestibulum. Aenean vitae pellentesque quam, non ultricies tortor.
</p>
</div>
```

Comment: What is "not working"?

Comment: What I am trying to accomplish -.-"

Comment: Re-read it. If the title doesn't explain it, then please don't answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As what Derek S said, try using pseudo elements: I created this simple demo that you can check out. It works on your code. So just change to what you need.

I would think this is what you are looking for.

By using:

```
.moiraitable:before {
    content: "";
    background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/owEfTJa.png");
    background-position: center top 100px;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    width: 500px;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -10;
}
```

[**Demo Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/62vSH/)

Comment: Works a lot better and you are much friendlier ^^

Answer (score 1):

The examples you provide are not the same as your situation, since you have a `repeat-y`. This causes the background to repeat in both vertical directions, so there is no "top" to your background image.

Try using pseudo elements as in [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9142777/1855126)